# Get last row of table attribute

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var table = document.getElementById(table1);
var lastRow = table.rows.length;

var country = lastRow.getElementById('Country');
country.setAttribute('class', "Country"+lastRow);
```

Im pretty new and I was wondering if this is possible?

Instead of

```
var Country= document.getElementById('Country');
```

As I have other id=Country because I am adding new rows..

**EDIT**

I know ID are unique. But I am cloning the last row so of course the IDs will all be the same.

Comment: You shouldn't have the same ID more than once on your HTML! Use a class instead.

Comment: "`As I have other id=Country`" you ***should not*** have *any* duplicate `id`s; an `id` ***must*** be unique within the document.

Comment: are you using prototype or jquery (or neither)?

Comment: Have you tried running this code?  The code you pasted will throw an error.  table.rows.length is an integer value, so you can't call getElementById on lastRow.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether they *are*, only that *they **have** to be*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ID in an HTML document is unique.  Hence there is no need to do sub-queries in order to find elements.  Instead always use `document.getElementById('Country')`

Comment: @LandY id's must be unique.  If they are not then you will run into many other problems

Comment: I have - $('#table tr:last').clone(true).appendTo('#table')

Comment: But I want to change 3 textfield boxes attributes before cloned

Comment: @LandY it's probably best to remove the ID, clone and then restore the ID to the original DOM element

Comment: @LandY basically remove the id, clone it 3 times, and then set the id on the original last row back to the value you just removed

Answer (score 20):

The last row of a table can be accessed from the rows property.

```
var lastRow = table.rows[ table.rows.length - 1 ];
```

However I think there is some confusion as to what exactly you're asking for.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to implicitly get the last cell.  Note that you can reference a particular object in the rows or cells array using the square bracket notation, and that due to arrays indexing starting at 0 you must subtract 1 from the length to use it as a valid last index.

This example show cases some of the things you can do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Table test</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function init() {

var table = document.getElementById("table1");

var lastRowIndex = table.rows.length-1;

var lastCellIndex = table.rows[lastRowIndex].cells.length-1;

alert( table.rows[lastRowIndex].cells[lastCellIndex].innerHTML ); // alerts the cell's containing HTML, or 9

var lastCell = table.rows[lastRowIndex].cells[lastCellIndex]; // contains a reference to the last cell

}



window.onload = init;
</script>

</head>

<body>


<table id="table1">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>


</body>

</html>
```

Suppose you had an arbitrary table with 8 columns and 4 rows as in the following example, and wanted cell in column 5 and row 3 to get that cell you'd want to grab a reference to the table (such as through `getElementById`) and then select for the right row and column through `rows` and `cells` making sure to subtract 1 due to arrays indexing starting at 0.  See this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Table test</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function init() {

var table = document.getElementById("table1");

var column5Row3 = table.rows[2].cells[4]; // contains a reference to the cell that is in the 3rd row, and 5th column

alert( column5Row3.innerHTML ); // alerts that cell's innerHTML (or Y)

}



window.onload = init;
</script>

</head>

<body>


<table id="table1">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td>Y</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
</table>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way to do this is :

```
var lastTr = document.getElementById('tabRecapCommande').lastElementChild.lastElementChild;
```

with `document.getElementById('tabRecapCommande')` returning the `<table>`
`document.getElementById('tabRecapCommande').lastElementChild`. returning the `<tbody>`
`document.getElementById('tabRecapCommande').lastElementChild.lastElementChild` the last `<tr>` of the `<tbody>`

if you `console.log(lasTr)` you will see your last `<tr>` element :)